# How to use constructor in Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

My code:

```
export class AppComponent {
title = 'chat';
constuctor(chatSvc: ChatService) { }

sendMessage() {
  let body = { message: "message"}
  this.chatSvc.sendMessage(body).subscribe((result: any) => {
    if (result && result.statusCode) {

    }
  });
}}
```

When I execute the above code it throws the error at the following line:

```
this.chatSvc.sendMessage(body).subscribe((result: any) => {


Property 'chatSvc' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
```

I had my chatSvc loaded in constructor but not sure why the error is thrown.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing in the constructor is assigning class members. In your case, the class member did not exist.

What your code was actually doing was accepting a constructor argument but discarding it.

Here's what you're probably trying to do:

```
export class AppComponent {
// This defines the class member but does not set a value
private readonly chatSvc: ChatService;
constuctor(myChatService: ChatService) {
  // This sets the value of the class member
  this.chatSvc = myChatService;
}
```

Luckily TypeScript has a shorthand syntax for creating class members by giving the visibility inside the constructor parameter list:

```
export class AppComponent {
title = 'chat';
// This both defines the class member and sets a value
constuctor(private readonly chatSvc: ChatService) { }
```

(I added `readonly` only because it's good practice and some linters will complain about read-write members that are never re-assigned.)

Comment: I tried putting in the way you said  and now I am seeing chatSvc as undefined. My component is standalone

Comment: @klp Does the code include the `@Component()` decorator immediately before `export class...`?